# Why can't I treat this function as an improper integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was wondering why the following question is integrable via improper integrals

$$\int_0^∞ 1/x^2 \, dx$$

Whereas:
$$\int_{x^2}^0 \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt$$

is not.

Comment: For (b), sdo you mean $\frac{\sin t}{t}$ perhaps?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Made the corrections

Comment: These integrals look completely unrelated to me.  Is your question just "why does $\sin(x)/x$ not have an antiderivative in elementary form?"

Comment: @newGuy101: the second integrand converges and the bounds are finite

Answer (score 1):

The first one is an improper integral because neither the interval nor the function is bounded. And in fact, it's a divergent improper integral.

The second one is a proper Riemann-integral, because the function is continuous (if you define it as it's limit at 0) and the interval is bounded.